# SoaUI Global properties and jenkins (with maven)

Tags: maven, soap, jenkins

Actually I have two question in the same post related to Soap, Jenkins and maven as a link between them

**Question 1 :**

Is there a way to choose some global properties (defined in soap) in the Jenkins project (just like adding parameters in freestyle project) ? And how ?

**Question 2**

My script has an xml output (a simple soap response) that I want to store somewhere (local or server), when I execute my script in command line (mvn test), I see my output file on my desktop, with jenkins, i cannot ? anyone know why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Solved, used testcase custom properties instead.